# Sending private messages to a list of Facebook pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a list of Facebook Pages of Businesses that allow you to message them privately. Is there a way that gives me the possibility to send the same message to every Page in that list? I've tried searching and haven't found anything that might work.

Just to reiterate, these aren't personal profiles or friends, but Facebook *Pages* of businesses that people can like, and who have enabled the option for customers to message them.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to send message at once. You have to do it individualy.